# how can i solve this compile error #Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, mingw-w64

**please update your includePath, Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit** these errors pop up in my vscode when I try to compile using mingw64.

I've attached my code below.

**This is my main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "compare.h"



int max ( int a, int b);

int main(){
    int maximum = max(135, 56);
    std::cout << "max : " << maximum << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**This is my compare.h file**

```
int max ( int a, int b);
```

**This is my compare.cpp file**

```
int max (int a, int b ){
    if(a>b)
        return a;
    else
        return b;
}
```

**This is my task.json file**

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "Build with GCC 13.2",
            "command": "C:\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "-std=c++20",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\*.cpp",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\main.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "compiler: C:\\mingw64\\bin\\cpp.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

all the other files is fine except the main.cpp

as soon as I remove the #include "compare.h" in my main.cpp, the error cleared but the problem is, I cant point to my other file without including it in main.cpp. any idea on how to solve the path issues would be appreciated

Comment: Two files `tasks.json` and `c_cpp_properties.json` control different things. The first is for building, the second is for intellisense. The problems you are reporting are intellisense errors not compiler errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience with Visual Studio Code (VSCode), the error you're encountering seems to be tied to the IntelliSense setup rather than the actual compilation process. Basically, it's struggling to locate the correct path for some header files, notably `compare.h`.

Here's a breakdown of how you can tackle this:

1. **Tweaking the `c_cpp_properties.json` File**:
   For its C++ IntelliSense, VSCode relies heavily on this file. When things go awry, it's usually because the `c_cpp_properties.json` is either set up incorrectly or absent.

   Navigate to the `.vscode` directory in your workspace and pull up the `c_cpp_properties.json` file. If you can't find it, just create one.

   Update or insert the following content:

   ```json
   {
       "configurations": [
           {
               "name": "Win32",
               "includePath": [
                   "${workspaceFolder}/**"
               ],
               "defines": [
                   "_DEBUG",
                   "UNICODE",
                   "_UNICODE"
               ],
               "compilerPath": "C:\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
               "cStandard": "c17",
               "cppStandard": "c++20",
               "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64"
           }
       ],
       "version": 4
   }
   ```

   Pay special attention to the `"includePath"` section. This tells IntelliSense to look for header files in all subfolders within your workspace. Tweak the paths if your setup deviates from this.
2. **Compiling Source Files Coherently**:
   I noticed your `task.json` is set to compile all `.cpp` files – which is good. Just double-check that both `compare.cpp` and `main.cpp` reside in the same directory. If not, your build command needs to account for all relevant paths.
3. **A Few Pointers**:

   - Maybe consider renaming your `max` function or nesting it within a namespace. This could help sidestep any overlaps with standard or other libraries.
   - If you're not too attached to your own `max` function, there's one in the C++ Standard Library (`<algorithm>` header) called `std::max`.

As a final step, restart your VSCode window (use `Ctrl+Shift+P`, then choose `Reload Window`). This should give IntelliSense a fresh start. Assuming everything's set up right, those pesky error indications should vanish, and you'll be on your way to compiling and running your program without any hiccups.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your `c_cpp_properties.json` (located in .vscode folder in your workspace) includes the correct paths for your compiler's standard library and other required directories.

Replace 8.1.0 with the actual version of your GCC. You can find out by running `g++ --version`.

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Win32",
      "includePath": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/**",
        "C:/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++"
      ],
      "compilerPath": "C:/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe",
      "cStandard": "c11",
      "cppStandard": "c++17",
      "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64"
    }
  ],
  "version": 4
}
```

In your `tasks.json`, you are using "`${workspaceFolder}\\*.cpp`" to include all .cpp files in the workspace folder for compilation.
**Ensure both main.cpp and compare.cpp are in the workspace folder.**